# Create tr with every four column in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have create and close a `tr` after every four column. I have some answers already been made on this type of question but I found it done in jquery. But I have to get this done in javascript only.

I write a code but it seems not right. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o37uaq4z/1/)

```
var html= "";
for(var i =0;i<9;i++){
    if(i%4 == 0){
  html+='<tr>';
  }
  html+="<td>"+i+"</td>";
  if(i%4==0 && i!=0 || i == 8){
  html+="</tr>"
  }
}
document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you think post can be improved

Comment: Note that in `i%4==0 && i!=0 || i == 8` if the third condition is true, the first two must be too, so it's redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your closing tag logic, it's not adding the closing tag in the correct location. To add the closing bracket in the right spot you can do this:

```
var html= "";
for(var i =0;i<9;i++){
  if(i%4 == 0){
    html+='<tr>';
  }
  html+="<td>"+i+"</td>";
  if(i%4==3){ //this will place the closing tag in the right spot.
     html+="</tr>"
  }
}
document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = html;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o37uaq4z/2/)

Comment: Closing tags aren't required for td, th or tr, so they can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks works fine. I guess I should put more effort before putting this question here :)

Comment: @RobG That's correct, but it does create html which is harder to read, imo.

Comment: @JanR—it's unformatted machine generated code, readability is moot. ;-)

Comment: Fair enough, must be my OCD then :)

Answer (score 0):

a tr after every four columns.

```js
var html= "";
for(var i =0;i<9;i++){
 if(i%4 == 0 && i != 4){
  console.log(i)
  html+='<tr>';
  }
  
  if(i==4 || i == 8){
  console.log(i)
  html+="</tr>"
  }
  if(i==4){
  console.log(i)
  html+="</tr>"
  html+="<tr>"
  }
  html+="<td>"+i+"</td>";
}
document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<table id="test"></table>
```

[Here is the fiddle,](https://jsfiddle.net/o37uaq4z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things by simply omitting the closing tags for th, td and tr elements, e.g.

```js
var html = '<table>';

for(var i=0; i<9; i++){

  if(i%4 == 0) {
    html += '<tr><th>' + i;

  } else {
    html += '<td>' + i;
  }
}
html += '</table>';
document.write(html);
```

Or if you like more concise code:

```js
    for(var i=0, html='<table>'; i<9; i++){
      html += (i%4 == 0? '<tr><th>' : '<td>') + i;
    }
    html += '</table>';

document.write(html);
```